# Adding a blur effect on a View Controller after segueing from it to another one modally

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a view controller(`vc1`) that contains a button. That button shows another view controller (`vc2`) modally. `presentation style` of the segue is set to `over current context`.

I've also created a `UIVisualEffectView` on a vc1 programatically (it covers the whole `vc1`'s `view`).

Now, I need to set a visual effect's effect to `UIBlurEffect`, but after the `vc2` is shown modally (which `view`'s `backgroundColour` is set to `clear`, so `vc1` is still visible behind `vc2`).

Is it possible to achieve without having to write a custom view controller transition and if so, how this could be done? If you know how to do this, I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: While it's a pet peeve of mine and I *wasn't* going to comment, I'm thinking it may help you a bit looking at your comments on the answer by @Nitish. Please remember, the difference between a *view controller* and a *view*. You *do not* apply a blur effect to a view controller - but many times you apply it to a view. IN code, you create a `UIVisualEffectView` (note, *not* a controller) and add subviews to it's content. All view controllers have a "root" view - in code, usually (but not always) `self.view`. Note that in the answer's code, it addresses that - and not the view controller.

Comment: @dfd, thank you for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blur transition does not come by default in iOS. So you need to customise code.
A simple solution would be to add a subview :

**Add the following code while transitioning to vc2 :**

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)    // Global variable
blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.removeBlurView), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "removeBlurView"), object: nil)
```

**Function for removing blur view (in vc1) :**

```
func removeBlurView()
{
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Add following in vc2 when you dismiss vc2 :

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "removeBlurView"), object: nil)
```

There are other ways to accomplish this as stated in [**Ray's tutorial**](https://www.raywenderlich.com/84043/ios-8-visual-effects-tutorial) and a closely related [**tutorial**](https://medium.com/@mohau/blurred-background-semi-transparent-modal-view-swift-3-xcode-tutorial-1f67566bb449)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the links to tutorials (I can't check them right now, but I'll do it later today). About your answer: I have added my blur transition as you've done in the code above. Now I try to make it fire when `vc2` is shown on top of `vc1` and I just can't figure out how to call it, to make it fire in the right time. `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` methods doesn't get called because I show the other `vc` modally and over the current context, so I'm trying to find out where else I can call it.

Comment: Call it when you open the vc2. Create Notification for remove the blurred view at the same time. Then when you close the vc2, post that notification and the blurred view will be removed.

Comment: So, am I getting it right, that you add the blur to `vc2`?

Comment: I just updated my answer to indicate the steps you should follow.

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan : Did that help ?

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you. I've tried both your code and the code from the second tutorial the link to which you provided. Both work, however your solution is clearer and more elegant. I wonder, can I use this solution while creating a View Controller custom transition (to dismiss the modal view controller and return to the main view controller, also, enabling user to interact with that animation)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use child ViewController mechanism.

```
let vc2 = VC2()

vc1.addChildViewController(vc2)
vc2.view.frame = vc1.view.frame

vc1.view.addSubview(vc2.view)
vc2.didMove(toParentViewController: vc1)
```